# VS code doesn't show settings defaults json file beside my customization

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to master working with visual studio.
In the *[Intro Vieos](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/configure)* the lecturer after opening *User Settings* shows that on the right side there are the default values for all settings and he can edit them by clicking on some icon beside each setting statement. Like the image below

[image]

I just do the same thing as he does. meaning I:

- press `ctrl+shift+p`
- search for *Preferences: Open User Settings*
- and I click on it when found

But what I end up in does not show the default setting values on the right, beside a tab on the left to write my own customization. I need to see all the current default settings to decide which one I want to edit. How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the lecturer uses an older version of Visual Studio Code. There was a change of the settings UI in August 2018, see here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27#_settings-editor

See this link to see how to use the settings UI: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

And there is always the chance to press `ctrl+shift+p` and type `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. If you go to a new line and type `""` you see the autocompletion list which shows all possible options.

EDIT: I just discovered that you can also restore the old behaviour. Open the settings and set `workbench.settings.useSplitJSON` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it really helped me.